# Can Delayed Job 'listen' for SIGTERM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-5

I have long running jobs on Heroku, and because the dynos automatically restart every 24 hours, I don't want it to interrupt some of my longer running jobs (4+ hours).

Ideally I can somehow 'listen' for SIGTERM and if the job detects that, it quickly aborts the loop its in and exits the job so that it can be re-run again by the next worker.

Here's a sample job:

```
class SMSPaymentDueSoonJob

  def max_attempts
    1
  end

  def perform
    User.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |users|

      #... do complicated work on 500,000 rows here ..

      User.where(id: successful_ids).update_all(sms_reminder_sent_at: Time.now.utc)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: delayed_job already listens for SIGTERM and tries to finish the current job before exiting. The problem is that Heroku allows 30 seconds to pass before issuing a SIGKILL, which causes immediate and unavoidable termination. EDIT: The dupe question should answer your current concerns, as well as the next problem you'd run into.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Thanks for finding this thread, I searched for a long time. I'll read through it.

Comment: what is the 'next problem' btw?

Comment: The next problem is that if you can't break out of the current job and set it up to restart when the dyno next comes online, your job will freeze. 30 seconds is a long time, but depending on your job, maybe not long enough.